# Huge amount of space in between radio button and selection text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am front-end stupid and can't ever figure this stuff out. For some reason I'm seeing an abnormal amont of space in between my radio button and the text.

[look on bottom of page](http://completesweets.azurewebsites.net/products)

I am using bootstrap and I feel as if it is doing this. How can I get that space to go away? There's no margin or anything on it current which is why I am a little confused.

```
 <div class="radio">
        <h4>By Price</h4>
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"> Low </label>
        <br />
        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"> High </label>
```

Comment: You're floating the radio buttons left.

Comment: You have this CSS rule that floats the radio buttons to the left. `.radio input[type="radio"], .radio-inline input[type="radio"], .checkbox input[type="checkbox"], .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
float: left;
margin-left: -20px;
}` If you don't understand what floating to the left means, perhaphs you should read up on CSS floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.radio{
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Also use a different div class.

```
<div class="radio col-sm-3">
```

Answer (score 3):

You're labels are floating left which means it's being pulled to the far left of your container. I would recommend wrapping your content in columns. So something like this would work...

```
<div class="radio col-sm-3">
    <h4>By Price</h4>
    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"> Low </label>
    <br />
    <label><input type="radio" name="optradio"> High </label>
</div>
```

If your content is then not centred, I would add this to your CSS...

```
.radio {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

That should centre your content.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because the Div with class "radio" has a default width of 100%.  When I change the css for .radio to width: 100px (or a percentage of your choice) then the radio button is much closer to the text.  You will also have to center the div with the margin-left and margin-right as follows

```
.radio{
    width: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: this answer worked as well, I really appreciate it I can only check one though.

Answer (score 1):

As stated, the radio buttons are floated left in CSS.
This is a CSS rule meaning they're being taken out of the flow of the document.
The result is that they're positioned relative to the parent div, instead of according to their relationship to other block-level elements (the labels). That's pushing them all the way to the left of the `form` element.

In your external CSS file (not "products.css" but the one w/the gigantic hashed name) find this line:

```
.radio input[type="radio"], .radio-inline input[type="radio"], .checkbox input[type="checkbox"], .checkbox-inline input[type="checkbox"] {
    float: left;
    margin-left: -20px;
}
```

The offending code is `float: left;`
Remove the float and the inputs should rest directly next to the text. 
Play with the margin settings to position it as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using:

```
<input type="radio" name="optradio"> Low <br />
<input type="radio" name="optradio"> High
```

I'm pretty sure it will work.

Comment: I agree with j08691 about the floating left buttons.

Comment: This didn't do anything, is it because it's in a form or something? And 'its' as in my radio and div.

Comment: I am literally front-end illiterate, how am I floating them left? ( I really don't know how I am doing that)

Comment: -1 All you did was remove the `label`. While this [probably] solved it, not having `label`s on form controls prohibits people with disabilities and/or cannot use a mouse from using the form/site

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Later i found out it was because i created a class for input like,

```
    .input
    { 
        width: 200px; 
        border: 1px solid #000; 
        padding: 5px; 
    }
```

Later i edited the input with some other name like,

```
    input.a1 
    { 
        width: 200px; 
        border: 1px solid #000; 
        padding: 5px; 
    }
```

and the problem solved for me;